# Why we need both setNoRender and disableLayout in zend

Tags: zend-framework

```
$this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(TRUE);
```

This is what we normally do to disable view. My question is why we need `disableLayout()`? When Layout itself a view helper why we need both to disable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because ,

```
$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(TRUE);
```

Only Disables the view , I.E. the phtml script associated with the action..

but if you use only that then, the layout which is central to the whole application will be loaded.. which will contain some css or js or anything related to central theme which is part of layout.

if you want to remove all that and just want the blank page then you must use both..

Comment: was used this with ajax responses `$this->_helper->json->sendJson($array)`, then output was same with `$this->_helper->layout->disableLayout()` and without it. Thanks for this info.

Answer (score 2):

To disable the layout of the action you need to use

```
$this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
```

for example if you are using Ajax request to the action, you can use this and the output of this request will be the associated view(phtml) of this action.

If you don't want to use this associated view you need to add following

```
$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(TRUE);
```

Now if you want to use different view file, you can use following

```
$this->renderScript('other.phtml');
```